# data.table column assignment within a loop

Tags: r, data.table, apply, lapply

This is what my data.table looks like. The three rightmost columns are my **desired** columns.

```
 library(data.table)
    dt <- fread('
        Product  Sales    A-CumSales   B-CumSales  C-CumSales 
        A          10        10            0          0
        B          5         10            5          0
        A          10        20            5          0
        A          20        40            5          0
        B          10        40           15          0
        C          5         40           15          5
        C          5         40           15          10
    ')
 dt[, Product:= as.factor(Product)]
```

The levels in my `Product` column are always changing. I am trying to do a loop where I am creating a separate column for each `Product` that computes the cumulative `Sales` of the respective `Product`.

I have tried:

```
for (i in levels(dt$Product)) {
  dt[,i:= cumsum((Product == "i") * Sales)]
}
```

Comment: I think your C-CumSales is incorrect, based on your input

Comment: Well, you can put parentheses, like `(i) :=`.

Comment: @Frank You are right.  I think i meant `dcast(dt[, 1:2, with = FALSE], Product + 1:nrow(dt) + rowid(Product)~Product,value.var = "Sales", fill = 0)[, c("A", "B", "C") := lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols = A:C][]`

Comment: @akrun Thank you for noticing. I fixed it.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I tried based on the OP's code:

```
dt <- dt[, .(Product, Sales)]

plevels <- levels(dt$Product)

dt[, c(paste(plevels, 'CumSales', sep = '-')) :=
        lapply(plevels, function(x) cumsum(Sales * (Product == x)))]

#    Product Sales A-CumSales B-CumSales C-CumSales
# 1:       A    10         10          0          0
# 2:       B     5         10          5          0
# 3:       A    10         20          5          0
# 4:       A    20         40          5          0
# 5:       B    10         40         15          0
# 6:       C     5         40         15          5
# 7:       C     5         40         15         10
```